# File upload via API in Express.js: Notification after file upload

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

We are trying to build a large file (size>30MB) upload from Android and iOS phones, for that created an **Express.js** API for file upload.

Endpoint: `user/upload`

```
uploadFile:function(req,res){

    //upload files to AWS s3 asychrnous
    s3.upload(params,options,function(err, data) {
        //when upload complete
        //need a help on this part
        if(data){
          //Send a notification to client
        }
    });

    res.json({
        status:true,
        'message':'Upload ongoing'
    });
}
```

When user requests the API (`user/upload`) it immediately give this response:

```
{
  status:true,
  'message':'Upload ongoing'
}
```

Because the upload is asynchronous. So how can I notify the client when upload completes?

Comment: I guess your `res.json({status:true,'message':'Upload ongoing'});` code block should come under your `if(data){....}` inside your `s3.upload` function.

Comment: Nop i can't do that because the file upload is take too much time thats why i made it as asynchronous

Comment: In that case, you can show some progress bar in the screen to keep the user informed that upload is progressing right?

Comment: but how can i keep track that progress from client ??

Answer (score 1):

For the specific usecase, I would recommend the following flow

1. From Express API Get [Pre-Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to Upload file to S3
2. Upload file directly to S3 from Mobile Client (Which will show the status as uploading in progress)
3. After upload completes, S3 will trigger a SNS push notification which will be sent to the Mobile device
4. Mobile device will read the push notification and change the uploading status in the application

Above flow is completely asynchronous and highly scalable reducing the load for your express API.

Comment: Thanks for SNS suggestion let me try it

Comment: Why did  I need a signed URL??

Comment: Rather you upload to S3 through your express API, you can directly upload to S3 in a secure manner to a private bucket(Reducing the load from the express API)

Comment: You mean direct browser upload??

Comment: Yes. Direct browser upload, or direct upload from mobile app for a private bucket.

Comment: Does any tutorial related to that ?? I've found something but it's browser direct upload it says nothing about the API upload

Comment: But how can i use a direct upload

Comment: Request a URL from Express API (Which will use AWS credentials and S3 SDK) and sent to client, client can then use it to upload the file to S3
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-generate-presigned-URLs-for-Amazon-S3-using-node-js